# How Can I Modify a Git Submodule So That It Is Attached to the Head

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repo that contains another GitHub repo as a submodule. I clone the parent repo using the --recursive option. Doing a git status on the sub repo reveals that is is detached from the Head; it is "tied to" a specific, previous commit. I then checkout the sub repo's master branch, thereby reattaching it to the head.

Here's the question: Is it possible to modify things such that, after doing the clone, the submodule will already be attached to the HEAD (the checkout step will not be necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that is the technique how submodules are implemented. In the parent repo you define a specific commit (via SHA-1) of the submodule which you depend upon. So if you clone the parent repo you get the exact commit you defined and are compatible with. Everytime you want your parent to depend on a newer commit of the submodule you have to manually tell it to and create a commit for this. That is also the reason why submodules may be fine if you depend on someone elses repository that you do not need to update too often, but are in my opinion pretty much useless if you develop both projects yourself at the same time.

Comment: @ Vampire Thanks for the info. I am learning. What technique do you use in situations like these? Such as two parents each needing the same sub, all belonging to me.

Comment: I am in the happy situation that I didn't have to decide this yet because I didn't need it yet. But you can read what we tell people in the #gradle IRC channel by going to https://jk.gs/git/bot/trigger.php and searching for `!subprojects`. Besides the possibilites there, you can also consider building a deliverable from the common project and add a binary dependency from the parent repositories. If you develop Java and use Gradle as build tool, you then can also replace the binary dependency by using a composite build with a checked out state of the common project.